# Laravel 5 Route::when() replacement

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to provide in Laravel 5.5 what 4.2 had with:

```
Route::when('*-ajax', 'ajax');
```

I had an option to attach a filter to all ajax routes, and since then I know that filters have been replaced with middleware, but I am getting an error that:

```
Attribute [when] does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in having implemented a global middleware for this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($request->url());

    if (key_exists('path', $parsedUrl) && strpos($parsedUrl['path'], '-ajax') !== false && !$request->ajax()) {
        return response('Bad request', 400);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request::is()`. Few details in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#other-request-information)

It accept multiple params as well.

[edit] You also have `Request::ajax()` which returns `true` when you perform an ajax request

Comment: and where would they use this?